# How to store inlined images in Outlook email messages into MHTML to view properly in a browser?

Tags: firefox, outlook, mhtml

My goal is to be able to store a Outlook email as a *single* file that will render properly on *all* platforms and browsers. MHTML is close, but I ran into a problem with inlined images:

Steps to reproduce:

1. Send to your Outlook email an email with an inlined image.
2. **Save As** the email as a MHT file
3. Open up the .mht file into Firefox
4. See that the inlined image renders as `cid:image001.jpg` which is of course not desired.

[image]

Is this an Outlook issue? A Firefox issue? A MHTML-cannot-handle-that type of issue?

### Update:

I stored the original .mht file, that would not render properly in Firefox, and examined it via a text editor, and found a section showing:

```
------=_NextPart_01D2ABD9.D009C5C0
Content-Location: file:///C:/744A9D04/CENSORED.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Type: text/html; charset="unicode"
```

Removing that section, saving it, and viewing it in Firefox showed the image.

But if I forward the original email to myself, the above "unicode" section disappears and is replaced with:

```
------=_NextPart_01D2ABD9.F8480C90
Content-Location: file:///C:/2A7414D3/CENSORED.htm
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
```

And for that one, Firefox renders the image correctly.

So there is something about that "unicode" section that is tripping Firefox up.

Comment: Does IE show the image Ok? MHT fiel is nothing but a MIME message with only the images included as attachments.

Comment: Yes IE shows the image correctly. I also tried it on Firefox Version: 52.0.2 on Linux and got the same problem.  Is this Microsoft's bug or Firefox'es bug?

Comment: I am not even sure FF can show MHTML files. Doe it show other MHTML files?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes it does show _most_ of the MHTML content. The rest of the message contents of the original Outlook message looks legible enough, but it is just these specific `cid:image001.jpg` parts are not rendered as I would expect.

Comment: But dos it ever show any embedded images?

Comment: Yes. I posted an update to my original post where I examined the internals of the .mht files with a text editor. This is sounding more and more like a Firefox bug.